# Can addition operator with a string as the first operand return a non-string?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Flow v0.52.0 is ok with:

```
"" + ""
"" + 0
```

but [not ok with](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAiDYDUYubZ4AMhuYAdgK4wxl5UUAmAplAJYUtP1gAuAJyoteAbwC+qIA)

```
"" + null
"" + undefined
"" + true
"" + {}
```

AFAIK, using an addition operator with a string as the first operand will always return a string. In fact, this is what Babel uses for [template literal transpilation](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=AYEg3gLgTgrgpgX3AMwIYBsDOjhA):

```
`${true}${false}` === "" + true + false
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Vanilla JS allows `"" + true + false` as well, so i assume its a limitation Flow has coded in themselves as it is legal JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow disallows most implicit type conversions. `"" + 0` is allowed as it is a common way to convert a number into a string, but there is essentially never a case where you want to convert `null` or `undefined` or any other types into strings implicitly.

> In fact, this is what Babel uses for template literal transpilation

Babel's defaults at the moment aim for a line between performance and spec compliance. If you look at [the `spec: true` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-template-literals/#optionsspec), you'll see that

```
`${true}${false}`
```

is equivalent to

```
"".concat(true, false) // Babel 7.x
```

where `.concat` is used to implicitly convert the values to strings using `.valueOf` semantics.

Babel 6 uses a longer version that has unrelated ordering issues:

```
'' + String(true) + '' + String(false) + '' // 6.x
```

where the `String()` function is explicitly saying "convert this to a string".

When you use the template literal syntax, you are asking for it to be stringified, whereas the original `'' + true` case does not, which makes sense because template literals are an explicit declaration of "I want a string", whereas the `+` operator is asking for concatenation, and most of the time implicit conversion isn't wanted.

Comment: The issue you've linked is golden, although it seems to apply to objects only. Apparently, for template literals Flow makes assumptions of what's used under the hood.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by objects only? Flow assumes that you're using spec-compliant template literals, which I think is a fair assumption, it's just that Babel makes different assumptions that mostly works.

Comment: I mean you can only break Babel's implementation with an object since you can't redefine `valueOf` on a primitive. Flow doesn't bother about that: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVADAJAbwC4BOArgKYC+uUAhjAM7kapA

Comment: Oh gotcha, fair then. I never actually looked at Flow's behavior, I thought you were saying it didn't complain in your question, but I think I just read too much into your template example.